# Need to get last 4 lines from a table, yet not getting any results

Tags: php, mysql

I am quite new to PHP and I am trying to get the last 4 rows from a product table.... I am however not getting any type of results:(

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong, I tried to use a for loop to change the `prod_id` each time in the named parameter but it somehow doesn't bring up any results can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

for ($prod_id = 4; $prod_id<=8 ; $prod_id++)
{   
    $query2 = "SELECT p_type, p_name FROM `products` WHERE prod_id = :prod_id ";
    $prod = $db->prepare($query2);
    $prod->bindValue(':prod', $prod);
    $prod->execute();
    $detail=$prod->fetch();
}
foreach($prod as $result)
{
    echo $result['p_type'] . ' ';
    echo $result['p_name'] . ' <br />';
}
```

Comment: what is the primary key of `products` table?

Comment: You can do something like `SELECT p_type, p_name FROM products ORDER BY prod_id DESC LIMIT 4;`

Comment: People already answered. Anyway if your database is mysql I strongly suggest you `mysqli` class http://php.net/manual/it/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @osnapitzkindle While mysqli is more specific (support of special features) PDO is more generic, thus portable. Why do you *stongly* suggest mysqli over PDO? Is there another disadvantage?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone exactly, just because PDO is more generic mysqli is optimized for MySQL databases, and it might be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using mysql, there is a simple solution to let the database do that:

```
SELECT p_type, p_name FROM `products` WHERE prod_id = :prod_id LIMIT 0, 4
```

But this requires to order the entries first, else you would get *some* products. This can be done by the database as well by adding

```
ORDER BY ...
```

Replacing the three dots by the name of the column you want to use to order.

Another thing is, that you execute 5 SELECTs but you could get all entries at once by using BETWEEN:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$query2 = "SELECT p_type, p_name FROM `products` WHERE prod_id BETWEEN :from and :to ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4";
$prod = $db->prepare($query2);
$prod->bindValue(':from', 4);
$prod->bindValue(':to', 8);
$prod->execute();
$detail=$prod->fetch();

foreach($prod as $result) {
    echo $result['p_type'] . ' ';
    echo $result['p_name'] . ' <br />';
}
```

This improves performance and reduces complexity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Since I see that you are using PDO, the way you can do this is like so:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

for ($prod_id = 4; $prod_id<=8 ; $prod_id++)
{
  $query2 = "SELECT p_type, p_name FROM `products` WHERE prod_id = :prod_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,4";
  $prod = $db->prepare($query2);
  $prod->bindValue(':prod', $prod);
  $prod->execute();
  $detail=$prod->fetch();
}
foreach($prod as $result)
{
  echo $result['p_type'] . ' ';
  echo $result['p_name'] . ' <br />';
}
```

The first tag that I added - The `ORDER BY id DESC` tag, will order the tables it retrieves in **descending** order, meaning from bottom to top.

The next `LIMIT` tag will, using the first number - Tell it where to start from (what entry to start from) and how many to get. So in our case we got the first entry in the table and 4 from it - Giving us the last 4 results from the database.

Here is some more information on `LIMIT` - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting any database,also your placeholder is different in query and when binding and you are iterating over the wrong results

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password,$somedatabase);

for ($prod_id = 4; $prod_id<=8 ; $prod_id++)
{
    $query2 = "SELECT p_type, p_name FROM `products` WHERE prod_id = :prod_id  ORDER BY prod_id DESC LIMIT 4";
    $prod = $db->prepare($query2);
    $prod->bindValue(':prod_id', $prod);
    $prod->execute();
    $detail=$prod->fetch();
}
foreach($detail as $result)
{
    echo $result['p_type'] . ' ';
    echo $result['p_name'] . ' <br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated:)